# Add HyperLinks to RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can I add hyperlinks to `RadioButtonList`?

I tried the following but it still renders as plain text.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" id="rdlTest">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<a href='Page2.aspx?1'>A</a>"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="<a href='Page2.aspx?2'>B</a>"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I know the following works but I would like to use `RadioButtonList` rather than `RadioButton`.

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoTest" Text="<a href='Page2.aspx?1'>A</a>" />
```

**UPDATE**

Some other code was messing this up. So there was no issue with my original code.
I had a function to clear and reload the rdlTest at `Page_Load` with `rdl.Items.Add(new ListItem("1","A")` and that is overriding the working markup.

Comment: I think you'd have to handle this on the rowdatabound event, through mark up this wont work.

Comment: The code you supplied renders as correct hyperlinks in my project...

Comment: Ray can you post the code where you edit the original code you posted to show the code that gives you the error to alleviate any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like ...

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chk" runat="server">

        <asp:ListItem Value="0"><a href="http://www.asp.net">asp.net</a></asp:ListItem>

        <asp:ListItem Value="1"><a href="http://forums.asp.net">forums.asp.net</a></asp:ListItem>

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

RadioButtonList and CheckBoxList should work similar.

Comment: I tried with `RadioButtonList` but still shows as plain text.

Comment: you may want to change <asp:ListItem Value="0"><a href="http://www.asp.net">asp.net</a></asp:ListItem>
to 
<asp:ListItem Value="0">"<a href='http://www.asp.net'>"asp.net</a></asp:ListItem>

Comment: @DJKRAZE, tried that too, but didn't change anything. Thank you tho.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, please see my update. The original code works but something else was messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign them an id, then wire up an onclick event in Javascript (or jQuery).

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="A" ID = "A"></asp:ListItem>

$('#A').click(function(){

window.location='Page2.aspx?1'

}
```

Comment: I want the user to select the radio button by click, but ONLY if they click on the text part of the radio button, I want it to navigate to the link.

Comment: Try putting a label inside the ListItem, and hook up the onclick event to the label.